# What is the difference between QtWebEngine and WebView?

Tags: qt, qwebview, blink, qtwebengine

I think the title explains pretty much everything.

But once again, how would you explain the roles & purposes of these two terms about displaying webcontent in `Qt` applications? If I use a `WebView`, does it automatically involve `QtWebEngine` or is it something else?

I have read in Wikipedia that `Qt` uses [Blink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blink_%28web_engine%29) as web engine, however on `Qt`'s official pages they don't mention the term `Blink` anywhere.

Comment: Vote to open: The other question is outdated, make reference mainly to QWebKit which is deprecated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since I can't comment directly on your post for low reputation reason, I am answering here. This question is very related : [QWebView or QWebEngineView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29055475/qwebview-or-qwebengineview).

Basically, QWebView uses WebKit as the backend, whereas QWebEngineView uses Chromium as the backend. These two links may interest you, both referring to the latest version of Qt (5.6) :

QWebView : http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtwebview-webview.html#details

QWebEngineView : http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtwebengine-webengineview.html#details

I am currently working with QWebEngineView and everything works pretty fine, I haven't tested QWebView though.

Comment: Yes that was pretty much all, what I could find so far. However, I need more detailed information than 2-3 sentences under details subtitle. Do you know where I can read more into it?

Comment: Keep in mind that Blink is part of Chromium. I think you should search for the difference between WebKit and Chromium and see what's best for you. And last thing you can do is looking at Qt sources in order to see how both are managed by Qt ^^

Comment: What do you mean by Qt sources?

Comment: The code source of Qt : https://wiki.qt.io/Get_the_Source

Comment: Do I have to make webkit while making Qt from source in order to use Qt WebEngine? Or can I say -no-make webkit?

Comment: I don't think you have to, but for your futures researches, you'd better install all of it