# Alternative to QWebView()

Tags: python, pyqt4, qtwebview

Since QWebView() is probably not available in Ubuntu 16.10 onwards, what is the alternate possibility to do something like the following:

    `view = QWebView()
    view.load(QUrl('http://example.com')`

Comment: What is your version of PyQt?

Answer (score 2):

Use [QWebEngineView()](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/api/qwebengineview.html) instead.

QtWebEngine is replacing QtWebKit. You can look into the following link for a comparison on them.
[QWebView or QWebEngineView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29055475/qwebview-or-qwebengineview)