# QWebView: disable external resources

Tags: c++, qt, qwebview

Qt's [`QWebView`](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qwebview.html) class allows to render some HTML content with [`QWebView::setHtml(const QString &html, const QUrl &baseUrl)`](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qwebview.html#setHtml) and of course it tries to load external resources if the HTML contains some references like `<script src="..."></script>`.

How can I turn this feature off for security reasons? I took a look at the header file and found no according virtual method to override and no according method to set the desired behavior.

Any dirty workarounds are welcome!

Comment: Can you do what you want via QWebSettings?

Comment: I have tried extremely restrictive settings with `QWebEngineSettings` (not `QWebSettings` and they are enough to disable JavaScript but not enough to disable loading of external content completely.

Comment: I have also tried overriding [`QWebEnginePage::acceptNavigationRequest`](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-6.2/qwebenginepage.html#acceptNavigationRequest) but it is not fine-grained enough. It only allows to block the entire page or nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I found two separate solutions for `QWebView` and `QWebEngineView`.

## QWebView

This solution works well for `QWebView` but I did not test it for `WebEngineView` (v.i).

First, derive a class from [`QNetworkReply`](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.6/qnetworkreply.html) that contains no data:

```cpp
#include <QNetworkReply>
class EmptyNetworkReply  :  public  QNetworkReply  {
    public:
        EmptyNetworkReply(QObject *parent=nullptr)
                : QNetworkReply(parent)  {
        }
        // implement pure virtual methdos of QNetworkReply
        virtual void abort()  override  {
        }
        // implement pure virtual methods of QIODevice
        virtual bool isSequential()  const override  {
            return true;
        }
        virtual qint64 bytesAvailable()  const override  {
            return 0;
        }
        virtual qint64 readData(char *data, qint64 maxlen)  override  {
            (void)data;
            (void)maxlen;
            return 0;  // number of bytes read
        }
};
```

Also derive a class from [`QNetworkAccessManager`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html) and make it block all requests by always returning an instance of the above `EmptyNetworkReply`:

```cpp
#include <QtNetwork/QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <iostream>
class RestrictiveNetworkAccessManager  :  public  QNetworkAccessManager  {
    public:
        RestrictiveNetworkAccessManager(QWidget *parent)
                : QNetworkAccessManager(parent)  {
        }
    protected:
        virtual QNetworkReply *createRequest(Operation op, const QNetworkRequest &request,
                                             QIODevice *outgoingData = nullptr)  override  {
            (void)op;
            (void)outgoingData;
            std::cout << "intercepting request to URL >" << request.url().toString().toStdString() << "<" << std::endl;
            // block request by not forwarding to  QNetworkAccessManager::createRequest(op,request,outgoingData);
            return new EmptyNetworkReply(this);
        }
};
```

Finally, create a `QWebView` with a `QWebPage` that uses the above `RestrictiveNetworkAccessManager`:

```cpp
QString myDocumentHtml = "<h1>foo</h1><img src=\"https://maxcdn.icons8.com/Share/icon/Logos/duckduckgo1600.png\" width='100%'><h2>bar</h2>";

QWebView *webView = new QWebView();
QWebPage *page = new QWebPage(webView);
page->setNetworkAccessManager(new RestrictiveNetworkAccessManager(webView));
page->mainFrame()->setHtml(myDocumentHtml);
webView->setPage(page);
```

console output of the above example:

```
intercepting request to URL >https://maxcdn.icons8.com/Share/icon/Logos/duckduckgo1600.png<
```

Btw, one might also want to disable JavaScript:

```cpp
webView->settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::WebAttribute::JavascriptEnabled, false);
```

## QWebEngineView

There is a solution that works with `QWebEngineView` (but not with `QWebView` as far as I can tell from the documentation). However, [it is probably a good idea to migrate from `QWebView` to `QWebEngineView`, anyways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29055475/qwebview-or-qwebengineview) (although I experienced an insane performance drop with `QWebEngineView`).

First, derive a class from [`QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor`](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-6.2/qwebengineurlrequestinterceptor.html) and make it block all requests *except the very first one*:

```cpp
#include <QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor>
#include <QWebEngineView>
class RestrictingInterceptor  :  public QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor  {
    private:
        bool firstRequestPassed=false;
    protected:
        virtual void interceptRequest(QWebEngineUrlRequestInfo &info)  override  {
            std::cout << "intercepting request to URL >" << info.requestUrl().toString().toStdString() << "<" << std::endl;
            info.block(firstRequestPassed);
            firstRequestPassed = true;
        }
};
```

Then, make sure that the `QWebEngineView` uses that intercepter:

```cpp
QString myDocumentHtml = "<h1>foo</h1><img src=\"https://maxcdn.icons8.com/Share/icon/Logos/duckduckgo1600.png\" width='100%'><h2>bar</h2>";

QWebEnginePage *page = new QWebEnginePage();
page->setUrlRequestInterceptor(new RestrictingInterceptor());
page->setHtml(myDocumentHtml);
QWebEngineView *webEngineView = new QWebEngineView();
webEngineView->setPage(page);
```

console output of the HTML loaded in the above example:

```
intercepting request to URL >data:text/html;charset=UTF-8,%3Ch1%3Efoo%3C%2Fh1%3E%3Cimg src%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Fmaxcdn.icons8.com%2FShare%2Ficon%2FLogos%2Fduckduckgo1600.png%22 width%3D%27100%25%27%3E%3Ch2%3Ebar%3C%2Fh2%3E<
intercepting request to URL >https://maxcdn.icons8.com/Share/icon/Logos/duckduckgo1600.png<
```

Btw, one might also want to disable JavaScript:

```cpp
webEngineView->settings()->setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings::WebAttribute::JavascriptEnabled, false);
```